# Force ubuntu 16.04 to always detect and use external display

Tags: 16.04, external-monitor

I am re-purposing an old laptop primarily as a file, music server and have installed ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

Laptop is an Acer Aspire, pentium processor, intel graphics.

External video output is HDMI and this goes through a KVM switch to my external monitor.

Problem is that ubuntu fails to detect the external monitor on boot and instead displays on the built-in display.  No combination of <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>, <kbd>F2</kbd>, <kbd>F5</kbd>, <kbd>F6</kbd> or <kbd>F7</kbd> will switch to external display.  The only way that I can switch is unplug HDMI cable from laptop and re-insert.  After this, the external display is enabled and I can KVM switch to another machine and switch back to my Acer - the display will remain on external.

However, if I open the settings app, open the display settings or run `xrandr` or `arandr`, ubuntu immediately switches to built-in display and I can only output to external display by removing and re-inserting the HDMI cable.

Also, I cannot output to external with the laptop closed even though I have ubuntu power settings to remain active at all times.

If I run `xrandr`, the external output disables and `xrandr` returns that only the built-in display is connected.  Re-connecting to external and then running `xrandr` again from the same command prompt shows both external monitor and built-in connected.

I have tried every combination of `xrandr` commands to force the external monitor to be detected and used by default but none work.

Any hints that can help me stay connected to an external monitor at all times would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Not a direct answer to your question but just want to make sure you are aware 16.04 ends standard support in a few weeks. No more help from this site and no more updates to the OS. Maybe time to think about an upgrade to 18.04 or 20.04

Comment: On some laptops this can be controlled via a BIOS setting; ie. you can force a laptop to use external-display only (useful if installed one is broken, or just default to a particular setup bypassing the need to press fn+monitor every time it's turned on to change default). I'm not sure if it would make a difference, but which kernel stack you've opted to use may also be useful knowledge (are you using the GA stack or HWE?) though I'd look for machine specific (BIOS setting) answers as they influence how Ubuntu boots. Are you talking Ubuntu Desktop or Ubuntu Server? and which stack? (GA/HWE)

Comment: Thanks David.  I was setting up 16.04 as backup for another samba server running 16.04 before upgrading.

Comment: @guiverc, I looked at the BIOS - nothing there.  Pretty certain this is a ubuntu issue as laptop used to run windows previously and had no problems.